# EditBox fieldInput.getValue() and spaces

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

Here is the issue.  I have an editBox which I am trying to retrieve the value from by server side JavaScript via the onClick event of a button named Add. It works until space is in the value, then it retrieves nothing. Code for the onClick events is as follows:

```
println("Button Clicked");
try{
var forkNumberInput:com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspInputText = 
getComponent("forkNumberInput");
var forkNum = forkNumberInput.getValue();
viewScope.ForkNum = forkNum;
println(forkNum);
} catch(e){
println( Error in Add button: " + e.toString());
}
```

When a space is in the text the viewScope doesn't get populated and nothing is written to the server log not even "Button Clicked".  No error is written to server log.

Answer (score 4):

If "Button Clicked" is not printed, the likeliest cause is that there are validation errors. Add a Display Errors control to make sure that's not the case.

Answer (score 2):

I second Paul's suggestion to add the Errors control. Besides that: Try to avoid to use `getComponent()` when all you want to do is grabbing the value. The idea of JSF, extending to XPages, is "data binding". Controls are bound to some data source for their value and you interact with those. `getComponent()` is meant to be used when you need to manipulate anything else.

So you would go and bind your control that scope variable `viewScope.forkNum` and you are done. Your button then grabs the value from there and does what it needs to do.

So in summary: Controls want to be bound. Data lives in models (not controls)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Paul - you led me to the right direction.  It turned out that there was a validateConstraint under Properties > data > validators.  I removed the validateConstraint and it started working. That's what happens when you copy design elements from one custom control to another.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please accept Pauls answer and add your own answer here as a comment to Pauls answer instead (and then delete your own answer)